# Same Toolbar for all activities - Something I'm missing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, toolbar, android-toolbar

**What I want:** I want to keep same toolbar for all my activities.

**What I have tried:** I made a BaseActivity and I'm having toolbar in it. I'm extending other activities to BaseActivity.

**What is the issue:** When I run the app. I'm not finding toolbar to other activities.

Below is my code.

**BaseActivity.java**

```
    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_lang_english:
                Toast.makeText(this, "English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case R.id.menu_lang_french:
                Toast.makeText(this, "French", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_base.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BaseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BaseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_base"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

**OutPut I'm Getting**

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Yeah you are . You have called `setContentView` in both classes . This will override the Base Activity one .

Comment: You could simply use **one** Activity. And a bunch of Fragments.

Comment: If I don't call `setContentView` for `MainActivity` how would I suppose to add widgets(e.g TextView, EditText) to `activity_main.xml` file.@ADM

Comment: @KlingKlang I can't. My project requirement is like that. This project I made for testing purpose.

Comment: If you want same `toolbar` in all activities then simply use `actionbar`. And instead of this `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` in your `AppTheme`.

Comment: Thank you @HeisenBrg That works very well. But in my project, bunch of other activities requires toolbar only instead actionbar. Do you have any idea how would I make a single toolbar same for some bunch of activities.

Comment: @MaulikDodia then simply use theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in the activity where you want to use `toolbar` instead of `actionbar`. And you can set different theme for each activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Looks great. Let me try.@HeisenBrg

Answer (score 0):

your screen can only have one layout at the same time MainActivity setContentView () is Override .

you can use Fragment instead of Activtiy

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add a Framelayout in your activity_base.xml. This layout will be a placeholder to put your specific screens. Hence all your specific screens will have the same toolbar and appearance.

Now from your concrete screens, you will NOT call the `setContentView()`. Instead call something like `putContentViewInTemplate(R.layout.activity_main.xml);`. This will replace the content_frame in template with actual screen. Here is a simple implementation,

```
protected void putContentViewInTemplate(int id) {
    mRootTemplate = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    mRootTemplate.addView(getViewFromLayout(id), 0);
}
```

Note that you are plugging the layout of your screen to the main template which is your `activity_base.xml`. Of course, you need to add the content_frame in `activity_base.xml`.

```
<FrameLayout app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```